# Sending message to vm deployed on Cluster with two nodes

Tags: mule, cluster-computing, mule-cluster

Am able to set-up a **cluster** as per mule documentation using **mule-ha-bundle-2.0** but with **two nodes** in **two different machines** connected in the same network and can deploy a flow having vm and logger as below.

```
<flow name="vmc-flow" doc:name="vmc-jc-flow">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
        path="vmq1" doc:name="vmq1-listner" />
    <logger
        message="Request hit to server: #[server.host] at time: #[server.dateTime] from the flow: #[flow.name] with payload: #[payload] and message id : #[message.id.toString()]"
        level="INFO" doc:name="log-info" />
</flow>
```

now my question is: **how to push messages to  that particular vm-queue?**

I have a used another (below) mule application which is again deployed on the same cluster but those are **not consumed** by the **listener 'vmq1'**

```
<spring:beans>
    <context:property-placeholder location="test-cluster-app.properties" />
</spring:beans>

<flow name="test-vmc-invoke" doc:name="test-vmc-invoke">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="${http.host}" port="${http.port}" doc:name="HTTP" path="${http.path}" />
    <expression-filter expression="#[payload !='favicon.ico']"
        doc:name="filter-favicon" />
    <set-payload value="#[string:from http]" doc:name="set-payload" />
    <logger
        message="sending message to vmq1 at time #[server.dateTime], flow #[flow.name]"
        level="INFO" doc:name="log-info" />
    <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
        path="vmq1" doc:name="vmq1-dispatcher">
    </vm:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

**Note**: Am able to hit the http and push messages to 'vmq1'

Please help me in understanding where am i going wrong.

Comment: Is there any way to monitor the message processing in mmc or a tool ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the user guide: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/VM+Transport+Reference#VMTransportReference-Considerations

> WARNING
>
> Each application in a Mule instance has its own, unique set of VM
>   endpoints. Thus the VM transport cannot be used to communicate between
>   different Mule applications.

Therefore, you can not use VM endpoints to establish inter-application communications. Use JMS endpoints instead.

Comment: Got it thanks David,  but still is there any way for VM to monitor that message processed/consumed in mmc or in any tool ?

Comment: MMC should be able to do that.

Comment: Actually, Mule features with version 3.5 "shared resources". You are now able to share a VM endpoint in different apps.

Comment: you can share vm with multiple APIs with a domain project.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find the link on how to use [Shared Resources](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Shared+Resources) in different Mule apps.

> Only the following connectors and related specifications can be
>   specified as shared resources at this time: 
>   HTTP/HTTPS 
>   VM 
>   JMS 
>   JMS Caching Connection Factory 
>   Database 
>   WMQ 
>   JBoss Transaction Manager
>   Bitronix Transaction Manager

Please note that the VM transport is an enterprise feature. Nevertheless the other types might be useful for your case too, for instance HTTP, or JMS.

Comment: +1 upvote to let us know about this feature. Thanks!